# Defining and referencing entities in XML?

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to create an XML schema for a document that looks something like the example below.
Is this the right way to define and reference entities within an XML document?
How do I specify in my schema that the `<palette>` contains references to existing `<color>` entities, not definitions of new ones?

```
<!-- define some colors -->
<color name="red">#ff0000</color>
<color name="green">#00ff00</color>
<color name="blue">#0000ff</color>

<!-- define different groups of the colors defined above -->
<palette name="rg">
   <color>red</color>
   <color>green</color>
</palette>

<palette name="gb">
   <color>green</color>
   <color>blue</color>
</palette>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a key on the (standalone) `color` elements (where the `name` attribute defines the key) and then a key reference for the `color` child elements of the `palette` elements, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#specifyingKeysAndtheirRefs for details.